# ASP.Net Core Client Side Validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am using ASP.Net Core 5.0.  I am trying to get my client side validation to work so that when you tab out of a required field, if the field is blank and required, the error message appears.

In my model I have -

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter in the name.")]
[MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The maximum length for the name is 100 characters.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I have a partial view _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml which contains -

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

In my view I have -

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Also in the view I have the field -

```
<div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="row">
         <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label col-md-3">Name</label>

         <div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" maxlength="100" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When the code is run the html is -

```
<div class="col-md-8 mb-2">
   <input class="form-control" maxlength="100" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The maximum length for the name is 100 characters." data-val-maxlength-max="100" data-val-required="Please enter in the name." id="Name" name="Name" value="The Name">
   <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

When I clear the field and I tab out, nothing happens!  I have noticed that the value attribute of the field in HTML is not cleared. Is that the problem and if so, why is not clearing?

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear whether you have included the jquery.min.js itself (the main Jquery include)

Comment: I have the following in my _Layout.cshtml - <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

Comment: hopefully you checked the developer console if you are getting any JS errors ..

Comment: I noticed that you are using local files .. I have used the combination below for these scripts and can confirm that the validation works - it may be worthwhile to test with these CDN based scripts just to be sure:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.10/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hi Phantom2018.  I checked the developer console, no errors or issues.  I have tried the CDN based scripts and still not getting the error appearing when I tab out.  Thanks anyway.